# CSS for Table display in Android/iOS

Tags: javascript, android, css, visual-studio, ionic-framework

I am trying to display the below table in an App.
**I can't use List or Grid**
The purpose of the below code is to allow a user to dynamically add, edit, delete the table data using javascript *table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML*

```html
<table id="data_table">
                    <tr>
                         <th>Wood</th>
                         <th>H(ft.)</th>
                         <th>Th(in.)</th>
                         <th>Qty.</th>                         
                         <th>Action</th>
                     </tr>

                     <tr id="row1">
                            <td id="name_row1">Sesa</td>
                            <td id="country_row1">12</td>                                                      
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
                                <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
                                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
                            </td>
                     </tr>

                        <tr id="row1">                  
                            
                            <td><input type="text" id="width_txt">asd</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="thick_txt">asd</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="qty_txt">asd</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="button icon ion-gear-a" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" onclick="edit_row('1')"></button>
                                <button class="button icon ion-android-done" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')"></button>
                                <button class="button icon ion-trash-a" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')"></button>
                           <!-- <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
                            <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save" onclick="save_row('1')">
                            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="new_country"></td>
                            <!--<td class="col col-20"><input type="text" id="wood_name"></td>
                            <td class="col col-10"><input type="text" id="height_txt"></td>
                            <td class="col col-10"><input type="text" id="width_txt"></td>
                            <td class="col col-10"><input type="text" id="thick_txt"></td>
                            <td class="col col-10"><input type="text" id="qty_txt"></td> -->                            
                            <td><button class="button icon ion-android-add-circle" class="add" onclick="add_row();"></button></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
```

Comment: So what is your qestion?

Comment: Q's: what  CSS should I write to show the above table properly on mobile phones. I making this code in VS2015 Ionic Cordova App.